# How to delete blank rows table rows in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering how I can delete blank rows from a table using vba.  Any help would be appreciated!  The code I currently have will create table just fine, and it will select the range I need to delete.  But I can't figure out how to actually get it to delete the rows I need.  There are two different tables I need to do this for.

Thanks in advance!

```
Worksheets.Item("Report").Range("H1:L50").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$H$1:$L$150"), ,xlYes).Name  = _
"Table1"

Range("Table1").Activate

Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: What do you intend to happen when a cell is blank, but other cells on the row are non-blank?  (`Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select`, which is [I think] the line you say is correctly selecting the cells to delete, won't discriminate between rows which are entirely blank and rows where there are some blanks and some non-blanks.)

Comment: It's best practice to avoid [`.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) - that may be causing issues, since you select something, then activate something after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I would delete the empty rows before I convert the range to a table.

```
Dim Target As Range
Set Target = Range("$H$1:$L$150")
Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftUp

ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Target, , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
```